# express router not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, routes

I created an express project using the express generator like following

```
express project_name
```

and

```
npm install
```

This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

These are my routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'iDanG Management' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have following index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  div.container

    div.row
      form(id='myform' action='' method='post')
        p Name:
        input(type='text' name='name')
        p E-Mail:
        input(type='text' name='email')
        input(type='submit' value='add')

    table(class='table table-hover' id='user_table')
      thead
        tr
          th Name
          th Email
        tbody

    script.
      $(document).ready(
        function() {
          $('#user_table').dataTable({
            "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
            "ordering": false
          });

        $('#myform').ajaxForm({ beforeSubmit:
          function (formData, jqForm, options) {
            $('#table').DataTable().row.add([formData[0].value, formData[1].value]).draw();
              return false;
          }
        });
      });
```

And following layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery.form.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.css")
  body
    block content
```

when I try to submit that form I receive following error:

```
Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/app.js:30:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15
    at next (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:14)
    at Function.proto.handle (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
    at router (/home/ubuntu/iDanG_Management/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
```

For the forms I used [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this problem? Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What's inside app.js?

Comment: @BenFortune my app.js is now in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are doing a post request and your routes does not have post handler.

May be add route for post:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //do something and return data here?
});
```

Comment: Even i suspect you are missing something in POST.